# Laravel Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, cross-origin-read-blocking

When I send a call from an Angular application to Laravel, I am getting the below issue

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8083/api/login_otp' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field ip is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
>   in preflight response.

I found a solution and did the below changes in CROS.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') 
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, X-Requested-With, x-xsrf-token');
    }
```

I added x-xsrf-token in Access-Control-Allow-Headers, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error message:

> Request header field ip is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

It says `ip` is not allowed.

Look at your code:

> ```
> 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, X-Requested-With, x-xsrf-token'
> ```

Your code doesn't mention `ip`.

Add `ip` to the list of allowed headers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define all your API paths in routes/api.php folder. In api.php folder you could have defined your path like below:

```
Route::get("/", [AngularController::class, "index"]); --> Incorrect Laravel API path
```

Then you must have set the base url as following in Angular:-

```
private url = 'http://local.new_practical.com/api/'; --> Incorrect Angular Base URL
```

An important thing to note here is that url defined in angular must be prepended with 'http://'. If it is there already, never set your api path like above mentioned Laravel API path. Instead, mention it the following way:

```
Route::get("getEmployees", [AngularController::class, "index"]); --> Correct Laravel API path
```

Therefore, set the base url defined in angular as:

```
private url = 'http://local.new_practical.com/api/getEmployees'; --> Correct Angular Base URL
```